# How do I detect if a port is currently in use? (c#)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, networking

I have been working on unit testing my network library, which involves starting up and closing many network connections (client and server both running on the same machine). I'm trying to wait for the port to become available after closing a previous socket, before opening a new connection.

I've tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```cs
public static int WaitForPort(int port)
{
    IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    
    while (ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections().Where(pr => pr.LocalEndPoint.Port == port).Any()) 
            ;
    
    return port;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your unit test involves testing ports on the host operating system, what you have is not a unit test.

Comment: Client applications should use port 0 that will let the OS select an unused port from the ephemeral port range. Servers should use a fixed port number to which they listen, and they should not be opening and closing the socket. A server can have any number of connections on the same port, and the connections get opened and closed, all the while using the same socket.